# Authentication on google: OAuth2 keeps returning 'invalid_grant'

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I started to configure google calendar on my new application. I almost made an exact copy of the authentication code displayed at google developers ( https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate ), but i keep getting the following error:

Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_grant'

I'm currently using Fork-CMS ( http://www.fork-cms.com ), a young lightweigth CMS. I correctly configured the config.php file of the google-api-php-client. (client-id, client-secret, redirect-uri, development key,...) and the redirect uri is correctly set on the google api's console. My code looks as follows:

```
<?php

/**
* This is a widget with a calendar implementation.
*
* @package       frontend
* @subpackage    events
*
* @author        Michiel Vlaminck <michielvlaminck@gmail.com>
*/
class FrontendEventsWidgetCalendar extends FrontendBaseWidget
{

    private $events = array();
    private $authUrl = array();

    /**
    * Execute the extra
    *
    * @return    void
    */
    public function execute()
    {      
        // call parent
        parent::execute();

        // load template
        $this->loadTemplate();

        // get data
        $this->getData();

        // parse
        $this->parse();
    }


    /**
    * Get the data from Google Calendar
    * This method is only executed if the template isn't cached
    *
    * @return    void
    */
    private function getData()
    {
        require_once PATH_LIBRARY . '/external/google-api-php-client/src/apiClient.php';
        require_once PATH_LIBRARY . '/external/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/apiCalendarService.php';

        $client = new apiClient();

        $service = new apiCalendarService($client);

        if (isset($_SESSION['oauth_access_token'])) {
            $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['oauth_access_token']);
        } else {
            $token = $client->authenticate();
            $_SESSION['oauth_access_token'] = $token;
        }

        if ($client->getAccessToken()) {

            $calId = FrontendEventsModel::getCalendarId((int) $this->data['id']);
            $calId = $calId[0]['calendar_id'];

            $events = $service->events->listEvents($calId);
            $this->events = $events['items'];

            $_SESSION['oauth_access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

        } else {
            $this->authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        }
    }


    /**
    * Parse
    *
    * @return    void
    */
    private function parse()
    {
        $this->tpl->assign('events', $this->events);
        $this->tpl->assign('authUrl', $this->authUrl);
    }
}

?>
```

When I open this widget-page for the first time, I get directed to google to authenticate the application. When I agree, I get redirected to my application and that's the point where I'm getting:

```
apiAuthException » Main

Message Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_grant'
File    C:\wamp\www\Officevibes\library/external\google-api-php-client\src\auth\apiOAuth2.php
Line    105
Date    Thu, 05 Apr 2012 08:34:47 +0000
URL http://localhost/calendar?code=4/YPUpFklKvhEeTcMm4moRth3x49oe
Referring URL   (Unknown)
Request Method  GET
User-agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.142 Safari/535.19
```

Comment: It's now called "Reset your client secret" instead of revoke.

Comment: In my case i was using previously deleted from console p12 key file...

Answer (score 22):

You should reuse the access token you get after the first successful authentication. You will get an `invalid_grant` error if your previous token has not expired yet. Cache it somewhere so you can reuse it.

Comment: I think this is no longer true. Using a refresh token, I was able to get an access token, and then another one before the first one expired. (I think this can be seen in OAuth 2.0 Playground also - https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ ).

Comment: Actually.. Im able to use the refresh_token to generate more access_tokens even if the current one hasnt expired. It will just give me a new access_token, and the previous one is still valid. So... Im not sure what you are saying is accurate.

Comment: That could very well be. I answered truthfully based on my experience back then. This is an ancient answer in Internet time. Things might have changed in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 9):

I was having a similar problem caused by the time on my server being incorrect. Make sure your  system clock is synchronised.

Comment: It was the problem I had as well. I am using a virtual machine to run the API on. directly after wake-up the time isn't synchornized yet.

Comment: I have tried many solution. This is the last solution I havent tried because I dont understand. What do you mean by "time on server being incorrect"? How to check if the system clock is synchornised?

Comment: I'd like to know too @John

Comment: I did the following to sync time on my Ubuntu Linux server which worked for me(assuming you do not have network time protocol(ntp) daemon installed):
sudo apt-get install ntp;
sudo service ntp stop;
sudo ntpdate -s time.nist.gov;
sudo service ntp start

Answer (score 8):

Go to your Google API Console ( https://code.google.com/apis/console/ ) and revoke your Client Secret under **Client ID for installed applications**.

Be sure to also update your code with the new Client Secret

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to security.google.com
2. Revoke access
3. visit the authentication url again
4. you will now get a new refreshtoken

Answer (score 1):

You'll also receive this error if you mistakenly try to authenticate your **ID Token**, rather than your **Access Token**.

So don't be like me - Make sure you pass the correct token into your code!

Answer (score 0):

You should take care of two things

1. You give access to some site (localhost or remote server)
2. I think every time you access `get_oauth_token.php` a new token is generated.

So make sure you use the new token and give permissions to the correct site.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue. The problem with "invalid_grant" is that it's basically a placeholder for any error that occurs in relation to the token. I found [this](https://blog.timekit.io/google-oauth-invalid-grant-nightmare-and-how-to-fix-it-9f4efaf1da35) article to be really helpful.