# How do I use OAuth 2.0 to access Google Calendar (Service Model)?

Tags: java, grails, groovy, oauth-2.0, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to get my Groovy/Grails application to speak to the Google Calendar API from Java, using a service model. For now I'll be happy with a simple calendar list. No matter what I do though, I end up with:

```
URI: /test
Class: com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException
Message: 400 Bad Request { "error" : "invalid_grant" }
```

The same user "googleaccounts@quirk.biz" owns both the calendar and the API Console App. Code as follows:

```
package quirkplanner

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.*;

class TestController {

    def servletContext

    private static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

    private static final String SERVICE_EMAIL = "12345678901234-abcdefabcdef@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
    private static final String CLIENT_ID = "12345678901234.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    private static final String PATH_TO_CERTIFICATE = "/WEB-INF/abcdefabcdef-privatekey.p12";
    private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_USER="my-google-admin-user@quirk.biz";

    def index() {

        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_EMAIL)
            .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"))
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(servletContext.getRealPath(PATH_TO_CERTIFICATE)))
            .setServiceAccountUser(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_USER)
            .build();

        Calendar service3 = new Calendar(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential);
        com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Calendar calendar = service3.calendars().get("primary").execute();

        render("ok")
    }
}
```

BuildConfig.groovy Dependencies are:

```
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.18.0-rc'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.18.0-rc'
```

And I also have a list of JAR's I'm using. The list it not complete, hence the BuildConfig dependencies. Ideally, I should really choose one or the other...

[image: Image of the Grails lib folder]

Comment: Any particular reason for **not** using [OAuth plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/oauth) or [Google for Spring Security OAuth plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-oauth-google)?

Comment: On a first glance I see two issues: 1. don't know where `httpTransport` is coming from, should it be `HTTP_TRANSPORT`. 2. You don't need `def servletContext` it is available in controller artefact.

Comment: @dmahapatro No reason. Just following Google documentation. httpTransport casing was a typo. Apologies.

Comment: Can you also add the dependencies what you have used in `BuildConfig.groovy`?

Comment: @dmahapatro added dependencies.

Comment: There are two different versions of `google-api-client` used. One from `lib` (which is not at all a good idea to start with) and the other from `BuildConfig`. I suggest you take some time and go through those two plugins I mentioned earlier. Also here is a [sample app](https://github.com/bagage/grails-google-authentification-example) using google spring security oauth plugin which would help as well.

Comment: As you got `invalid_grant` error, have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025698/authentication-on-google-oauth2-keeps-returning-invalid-grant?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that could try:

1. Drop and re-create your private keys in the Google Console.
2. Share one of the calendars from within the Google Calendar of the service account owner (googleaccounts@quirk.biz) with the SERVICE_EMAIL address.
3. Do not try to impersonate an account. Remove `setServiceAccountUser(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_USER)`

Be sure to use the SERVICE_EMAIL for the

```
.setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_EMAIL)
```

as you have correctly done. Google's documentation is not clear on this but using the Service Account ID will not work.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

[This link might solve your purpose, it has full example of GoogleCredential](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/06/google-services-authentication-in-app_20.html)

[image]