# Google oauth SSL certificate error

Tags: ssl, oauth, google-oauth

I'm trying to use Google oauth api for gmail signup in one of my website.
But I'm getting below error:

```
SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. 
Retrying with the CA cert bundle from google-api-php-client.
```

I'm stuck in this issue for about 1 day. Have searched in google but didn't find anything helpful. and I'm not Good in server setup.

so can anybody help me to solve this issue.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the issue which I mentioned above. I have just regenerated the "client secret" and used it then it solves my issue.

I got help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025698/authentication-on-google-oauth2-keeps-returning-invalid-grant)